# Flask-WTForms - QuerySelectField to set form select option values

Tags: python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have two [models](http://test.com) - `Employee`, which has a foreign key reference to `Role`.

**views.py**:

```
@admin.route('/employees/assign/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def assign_employee(id):
'''
Assign a role to an employee
'''
check_admin()

employee = Employee.query.get_or_404(id)

# prevent admin from being assigned a role
if employee.is_admin:
    abort(403)

form = EmployeeAssignForm(obj=employee)
if form.validate_on_submit():
    employee.role = form.role.data
    db.session.add(employee)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('You have successfully assigned a role!')

    # redirect to the employees page
    return redirect(url_for('admin.list_employees'))

return render_template('admin/employees/employee.html',
                       employee=employee, form=form,
                       title='Assign Employee')
```

**forms.py**:

```
class EmployeeAssignForm(FlaskForm):
'''
Form for admin to assign roles to employees
'''
role = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: Role.query.all(), get_label='name', 
                        allow_blank=True, blank_text=(u'Select a role'), 
                        get_pk=lambda x: 'id')
submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Right now, with the `get_pk=lambda x: 'id'`, I get `<option value="id">` in my html form web view, and regardless of what `Role` option I select, the first option always gets selected.

How do I set the `Role`'s `id` to the option value in my form and select it?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try `get_pk=lambda x: x.id` instead.